# Java ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException error in snake game

Tags: java, arrays, swing, compiler-errors, awt

I am trying to build a snake game. I have almost completed it. The problem is that sometimes when the snake eats the enemy object, this error pops up --->

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 33
```

er.java:814)

This is the location cell for the enemy --->

```
private int[] enemyYpos = {25,50,75,100,125,150,175,200,225,250,275,300,325,350,375,400,425,450,475,500,525,550,575,600,625,650,675,700,725,750,775,800,825,850};
private int[] enemyXpos = {100,125,150,175,200,225,250,275,300,325,350,375,400,425,450,475,500,525,550,575,600,625};
```

And this is for the random number --->

```
private int xpos = r.nextInt(34);
private int ypos = r.nextInt(20);
```

Now i use these to paint the enemy by using a for loop inside which the location of enemy is defined -->

```
 enemy = new ImageIcon("E:\\Netbeans\\old files\\Game\\src\\game\\bug.png");
    if((enemyXpos[xpos] == snakeXlength[0] && enemyYpos[ypos] == snakeYlength[0])){
    lengthsnake++;
    xpos = r.nextInt(34);
    ypos = r.nextInt(20);
    }
    enemy.paintIcon(this, g, enemyXpos[xpos], enemyYpos[ypos]); //The Exception error shows that the mistake is in this line
```

I hope this much info is enough. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you swapped the number of `x` elements and the number of `y` elements. Easiest fix. Change your generators to use the length of the arrays instead of magic numbers.

```
private int xpos = r.nextInt(enemyXpos.length);
private int ypos = r.nextInt(enemyYpos.length);
```

and

```
xpos = r.nextInt(enemyXpos.length);
ypos = r.nextInt(enemyYpos.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are mixing your Xs and Ys. It should be

```
xpos = r.nextInt(20);
ypos = r.nextInt(34);
```

and not the other way around.